# NFC - How to tell Application not to follow the usual intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, nfc, foreground, dispatch

I am writing an App that starts when a Tag with plaintext is read.
It takes the integer saved on it to search in a database for some stuff.
I like it that it starts and searches automatically, but i have one problem:
The App has an Activity to write/overwrite Tags. To get there you have to tap a button.
When I try to overwrite (write int into editText and activate writing per tap on button) a tag, it changes the activity and searches in database (when the tag has already an id).
When I try to use enabled foregrounddispatcht, it doesn't change the activity, but I am no longer able to detect the tag...
Any suggestions? ;)

btw. NFC is a completely new subject for me.

```
Manifest

<activity
    android:noHistory="true"
    android:name=".WriteNfcTagActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_write_nfc_tag">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: check this post for reading/writting data from and into nfc tags. [link](http://elsoufy.blogspot.fr/2012/10/readwrite-nfc-tag-in-android.html)

Comment: Thank you! The article helped me, I could solve the problem! ;)